# How can i stop my team using raw strings as JSX children in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, eslint

We have an enterprise React app for our product.

All strings we render to users such as 'Login', 'Browse Products' that need to go through translation and some devs usually hardcode these into the JSX rather than call a function to return a rendered string.

Is there a tslint/eslint rule I can use to stop users from writing stuff like `<p>Some string</p>`?

Comment: now sure why would u do it. we generally put strings as Constants if they are used in multiple paces. otherwise it should be fine to put them in jsx. also it helps in searching in codebase fast. just my opinion

Comment: @hannadrehman you missed the translation. So if your app supports 50 languages, you define 50 constants to say "hi"?

Comment: @hannadrehman the question is about enforcing *translatability*, which means that all visible text must come from message catalogs.

Comment: sorry my bad. i did miss the translation part

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-i18n and https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-i18next it checks that all the constants are translated using i18n